# Is it possible to access a child object from the errors on an active record parent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Given the relationship expressed below:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children, :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :child
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent

  validates :name, :presence => true
end
```

Let's assume we have a parent object with multiple children, one or more of which have errors that cause parent.valid? to return false.

```
parent = Parent.new
parent.build_child(:name => "steve")
parent.build_child()
parent.valid?
```

Is there a way to access the child element that caused the errors when looking at the parent.errors object?

Comment: You could look over the children...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As John suggested in the comments, I ended up ignoring the errors added to the parent for the children and traversing the children and adding their errors manually. The issue was complicated by having a couple has_many :through relationships, but John's suggestion was the essence of what I ended up using.

Comment: If you don't mind, can you show how you ignore errors for child objects?

Comment: @Mohamad I was creating a secondary hash of errors, so ignoring the errors for children was as simple as ignoring all the errors where key.split('.').size > 1

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could do it. Add to your `Parent` model

```
validates_associated :children
```

After that you can call `errors` method on every parent's child to find validation errors. Something like this to see child error messages

```
parent = Parent.new
parent.build_child
parent.valid?
parent.children.first.errors.messages
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding my solution as I hope it's helpful:

```
class Parent < AR
  has_many :children, inverse_of: :parent
  validates_associated :children, message: proc { |_p, meta| children_message(meta) }

  def self.children_message(meta)
    meta[:value][0].errors.full_messages[0]
  end
  private_class_method :children_message
end

class Child < AR
  belongs_to :parent, inverse_of: :children
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```